# iMacros - checkboxes

Tags: excel, imacros

On a web page I have 3 checkboxes, on my excel file I have a column with three different words: first, second and third (some are blank). I would like to check specific checkbox based on the value from cell.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks
Karol

Answer (score 0):

I manage to do it by adding the:

```
*&&VALUE:{{!COL8}} CONTENT=YES
```

into the part with my INPUT:CHECKBOX line.